# dumpe2fs - lifetime writes - what is it

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk

For example, if I run:

```
sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda1
```

I get detailed information about the partition.

I'm confused about this part, `Lifetime` writes, returns the following for my boot partition:

```
Lifetime writes:          12 kB
```

What does this `12 Kb` mean?

This is full output:

```
user@root:/data$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sdb1
dumpe2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          <not available>
Filesystem UUID:          5524d5a6-4635-48a6-8cd9-a636e3ad2b2c
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype sparse_super large_file
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              121680
Block count:              486144
Reserved block count:     0
Free blocks:              477783
Free inodes:              121669
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      118
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8112
Inode blocks per group:   507
Filesystem created:       Thu Mar 27 03:18:09 2014
Last mount time:          Thu Mar 27 03:18:34 2014
Last write time:          Thu Mar 27 03:18:56 2014
Mount count:              1
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Thu Mar 27 03:18:09 2014
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          12 kB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      8f43123d-1451-4047-a26c-d5227fd80240
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's all the writes in Bytes that the file system has since its creation. In your case only 12kB has been written since the creation of the partition. Remember that `dumpe2fs` reports the value as it was at the time when the file system was last unmounted, which could be wrong or obsolete in mounted file systems.

Comment: Great you for explained.

Comment: But why is wrong? This partition is boot partition and didn't takes 12 kB of space.

Comment: @MarinSagovac it is a blanket statement about relying on output from dumpe2fs on a mounted filesystem.  This field in particular though should be accurate and you can query it in realtime through sysfs as I mention in my answer.

Comment: is there a limit to that lifetime write ? can it "roll over" ? or will it change to a scientific  notation for bigger numbers?

Answer (score 8):

According to the [ext4 manual](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt) this is the total number of bytes written to the filesystem since it was created.  You can also query this value in kB by examing this file in the sysfs:

```
/sys/fs/ext4/<DEVICE>/lifetime_write_kbytes
```