# ext4 inode size, shown by dumpe2fs

Tags: filesystems, ext4

Manpage about `mke2fs` says "mke2fs creates 256-byte inodes by default". I've formatted my small (320MB) test partition with command:

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdc1
```

The defaults for the `mke2fs` are below:

```
[defaults]
  base_features = sparse_super,filetype,resize_inode,dir_index,ext_attr
  default_mntopts = acl,user_xattr
  enable_periodic_fsck = 0
  blocksize = 4096
  inode_size = 256
  inode_ratio = 16384

[fs_types]
...
  ext4 = {
           features = has_journal,extent,huge_file,flex_bg,uninit_bg,dir_nlink,extra_isize
           auto_64-bit_support = 1
           inode_size = 256
  }
...
```

Then I ran `dumpe2fs` and it showed me:

```
...
Inode size:           128
...
```

The program version is below:

```
dumpe2fs 1.42.8 (20-Jun-2013)
    Using EXT2FS Library version 1.42.8
```

Also, the superblock field `s_inode_size` = 128 (I read the superblock directly by `pread64`).

So, what would be the actual inode size in my case?

(I'm on Ubuntu 3.11, which runs as a guest VM in VMWare Fusion)

Answer (score 1):

As said with [another related answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121701/41104), you can't trust dumpe2fs in a mounted partition. It's very likely that it's erroneous or outdated. Unmount the partition and try again.

Comment: The partition is not mounted. But I think I should trust the superblock, don't I? And I've just tried tune2fs - it has shown me 128 as well. So, what the story about default size = 256?

Comment: How shall the inode size be an outdated information? That doesn't make sense. Just that you were right in the other answer doesn't mean that any information from `dumpe2fs` on a mounted volume is unusable.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I'm not saying that "it is" but "it is very *likely*". Nor I'm saying that dumpe2fs is unusable, but that is not always correct.